# How to use Hibernate ResultListTransformer in Spring JPA Repository?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, projection

Vlad Mihalcea describes in [How to fetch a one-to-many DTO projection with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/one-to-many-dto-projection-hibernate) a use case I want to implement in a Spring Data `JpaRepository`.

The code in question is the following one:

```java
List<PostDTO> postDTOs = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p.id as p_id,
           p.title as p_title,
           pc.id as pc_id,
           pc.review as pc_review
    from PostComment pc
    join pc.post p
    order by pc.id
    """)
.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
.setResultTransformer(new PostDTOResultTransformer())
.getResultList();
```

Is there a way to somehow get this behavior of setting a `ResultTransformer` in a `JpaRepository` without directly relying on the `EntityManager`? I'm looking for something like that:

```java
@ResultTransformer(PostDTOResultTransformer.class) /* or any solution that will do the job */
@Query("""
        select p.id as p_id,
               p.title as p_title,
               pc.id as pc_id,
               pc.review as pc_review
        from PostComment pc
        join pc.post p
        order by pc.id
        """)
List<PostDTO> findAllWithComments();
```

Of course there is no `ResultTransformer` annotation, the only thing I know that would do something similar is `@SqlResultSetMapping`, but afaik it ends with *Constructor Mapping* and is not capable of mapping one-to-many collections.

Is there a way to achieve what I want in an annotation driven approach or do I have to go back to using the `EntityManager` to benefit from directly result transformed DTO mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything appart align your JPQL query "AS" with your DTO field's name

See example here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: This is only true as long as the data retrieved fits the structure and type of a simple dto. However, as soon as type conversions and deeper structures become necessary, the result must be transformed.